# Using KeyboardEvent in a VPS

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have a VPS that i access by Remote Desktop Connection. In this VPS i run several Delphi applications that automate tasks. For these tasks i simulate keyboard presses by using the KeyboardEvent Windows API.

It works fine as long as i'm logged on the machine via RDC. When i logoff, the Delphi app keep running, but no KeyboardEvent works anymore.

Is there a way to fix that, or API alternatives that can send keys even if not logged on the VPS ? I can't be connected on the VPS all the time...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where do you expect the keys to come from when you're not connected to the VPS?  Also, why not auomate your apps in a way which doesn't require keypresses?

Comment: @MartynA Well i expect the keys come from the API, not a physical keyboard ;)

Comment: Keyboard focus requires interactive login I guess.

Comment: Faking KB input is the ultimate last-ditch automation hack.  Any other alternative should be preferred if it exists.  Is there really no other way to automate what you're doing other than this?

Comment: The keys certainly cannot come from the *KeyboardEvent Windows API* as there isn't such a thing.

Comment: @J... For what i want to do in my VPS i don't know other way : /

Comment: @delphirules If you could tell us what you were doing, we might be able to tell you another way.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution for this issue, but could find a workaround : if you install a new virtual machine INSIDE the VPS, the KeyboardEvent will work even if you disconnect from the VPS itself, because the virtual machine will keep running. Not an ideal solution but so far the best i could find.